# Hide background image in certain media query values

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide the background image I'm using only in mobile view.

```
html{
background: #fff url('//www.xxxxxxxxx.xxx/gray.jpg') center top no-repeat;
background-attachment: initial;
background-size: contain;
background-position-y: 0;
}
```

But when I do this:

```
@media (max-width: 425px){
background: transparent !important;
}
```

The background doesn't recognize the query rule set for HTML. How can I do this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Alberto, I've updated the title to be more specific to your question. Feel free to roll back if I've missed something.

Answer (score 3):

You must use a CSS selector inside the media query aswell. In this case add `html { ... }`.  Try this:

```
@media (max-width: 425px){
    html {
        background: transparent !important;
    }
}
```